# Laravel ORM Model Hierarchy?

Tags: php, orm, laravel, laravel-3

I want to create a One-to-Many relationship for one model.

Exactly I want to build a hierarchy of categories.

For that I have a migration script that creates a foreign key / column category_id.

In the database this is easy. Create one category "Cars". Create another category "Audi" with parent id linked to id of "Cars".

But when I create a function in the ORM model like this:

```
public function category() {
    return $this->belongs_to('Category');
}
```

Then I create an infinite loop.

What am I doing wrong? Maybe this is just not possible?

Thank your for your suggestions!

Comment: I don't see why that would create an infinite loop. Maybe with auto loading in play? I've done hierarchical categories in this way without much of a problem. I've also built has_many_and_belongs_to relationships within the same table/model ie: tag_tag.

Comment: Can you give me an example (migration script + model code), that works for you? I'm very interested in it! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I got this working with the ORM functionality. This works fine, my view can handle with it!

```
public function children() {
    return $this->has_many('Category','category_id');
}

public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongs_to('Category','category_id');
}
```

Comment: You cann't call a method `parent`

Comment: For the newer versions of Laravel it should be `hasMany` and `belongsTo`. But thanks for the Idea :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I ended up by writing a parent() function, that returns the value of a where clause:

```
public function parent()
{
    return Category::where('id', '=', $this->category_id)->first();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For one-to-many you need 2 tables.

Table 1: Types

Table 2: Vehicles

In table 1 you have ID, name (1, car)

In table 2 you have ID, name, type (1, audi, FK to Types.ID)

In SQL, this'll look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Vehicles
WHERE type = 1
```

Don't know if this helps :)

Comment: Okay, this is what I already knew so far. Is there an implemented laravel way to create relationships on one table?

Comment: Have you looked into using the query builder and using the join function to create your relationships?

Comment: Okay I had a look at that. Seems another good way to realize it. Thank you!